# Android - need a number flip animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm developing an Android application to read "electric meters". The user enters the counter - the application calculates the consumption and sends it to a server.

The representation of the counter should look like a old electricity meters 
[old electricity meter](http://www.ip-symcon.de/forum/attachments/f52/8015d1272437369-zahlen-bildern-stromzaehler_1.jpg)

I've already integrated the counter-numbers as images. I will have an animation that if the user enters a number (keyboard) then the relevant section begins to rotate to the correct number position.

For example: The user enters the number 5 for the first digit, then rotate the digit from 0-5. The animated numbers flip to the correct position. How can I do this? Any idea?
thank u!!!

Comment: There is a really good one somewhere on [SO] but I couldn't find it ... but here's somehting to get you started http://kevindion.com/2010/12/android-odometer-ui-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: If anyone looking for a flip timer check this out : https://github.com/anugotta/FlipTimerView

Answer (score 15):

There is a custom view which I've created for a custom application. Initially, i also tried searching for this type of view but couldn't found any. So created one of my own.

You can see the code here: https://github.com/Vinayrraj/Android-FlipDigitView

Also this video might help you: http://youtu.be/d6-M2nN2Gzg

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can take a look to [Ticker](https://github.com/robinhood/ticker), an Android text view with scrolling text change animation:

[image: Ticker]

> Ticker is a simple Android UI component for displaying scrolling text.
>   Think about how an odometer scrolls when going from one number to the
>   next, that is similar to what Ticker does. The Ticker handles smooth
>   animations between strings and also string resizing (e.g. animate from
>   "9999" to "10000").

Answer (score 3):

I'd have one spinning animation - but make it fast and blurred so you can't see what number it's on - play that for 1 second, then replace with the correct position - it's a trick, but will save you doing lots of different animations.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your need, I would use two different approach: 
1) one big animation with numbers from 0 to 9; when you have an inoput number, you should launch the animation and stop at the right frame (just a math calculation matter);
2) one animation for each number; you could think about a number flipping as if its rotating on itself vertically; then, when the user put his number X, you have to flip between X different animations until the good one and stop.