# Java library counter number

Tags: android

Anyone know a library that allows this kind of counter displays? Or the name of this type of display?

[image]

Thank You

Comment: Search for "android flip number" or "android flip counter".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8181868/438992, so this is a dupe as well as OT. The answer provided to this OT question is a dupe of the answer to that older question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [FLipDigitView](https://github.com/Vinayrraj/Android-FlipDigitView) by [Vinay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812131/vinay). A video of the same can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6-M2nN2Gzg).